# Cell tower to cell phone encrypted communication

Tags: encryption, mobile, gsm, cellular

I have done some search here but I can't understand **how phones and antennas share the keys used for encryption and decryption**.

As far as I understand, mobile phones today use LTE i.e 4G (sometimes they downgrade 3G, 2G etc because of coverage as well) and as part of the encryption protocol they use a stream cipher (SNOW3G for example).

In general stream ciphers use a binary key generated somehow (maybe a PRNG) applied Bitwise to encrypt and then decrypt data, in a simple XOR operation.

Without the key, the attacker isn't there to decrypt data, even for a short message as the key is applied bitwise. But I don't know how this key is securely shared between the phone and the cell tower.

Because the phone is moving and maybe changing cell towers, this mechanism has to be pretty robust, so I am curious about it.

A conceptual explanation or beginner-friendly writeup is greatly appreciated.